# Div with class 'input-group' Shrinking form width in Django Crispy Forms

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

I have a form (class `"form-control mb-3"`) with a MultiWidget select field and text field which currently renders as:
[image]

I want to use crispy forms to render the time field in line with the date field and tried to do so by wrapping the fields with a `div` of class `input-group`:

(forms.py:)

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.label_class = 'form-label'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            
            Div(
            MultiWidgetField('date', attrs=({'style': 'width: 33%; display: inline-block;'})),
            Field('time', css_class='form-control'), 
            css_class="input-group"

            )  
        )
```

(html page:)

```
<form class="form-control mb-3" action="{% url 'change_event' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% crispy event_form event_form.helper %}

            <input type="submit" value="Make Changes">
            <input type="hidden" name="post-id" id="post-id-input" value={{ post_pk }}>
        </form>
```

However, it shrinks the entire `input-group` div to about half the width of the form, making it hard to read:
[image]

Is there a different class which renders the div at the full width or some other way of doing this with crispy forms?

(NB: Using `MultiField` just removes the date entirely. Previously when trying to use MultiField I got the error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist: bootstrap/multifield.html